# What is the most simple SQL command to show CONSTRAINT_NAME column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I did it yesterday, but already forgot.

```
SQL> DESC USER_CONSTRAINTS;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -----------------

 OWNER                                              VARCHAR2(120)
 CONSTRAINT_NAME                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 CONSTRAINT_TYPE                                    VARCHAR2(1)
 TABLE_NAME                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 SEARCH_CONDITION                                   LONG
 R_OWNER                                            VARCHAR2(120)
 R_CONSTRAINT_NAME                                  VARCHAR2(30)
 DELETE_RULE                                        VARCHAR2(9)
 STATUS                                             VARCHAR2(8)
 DEFERRABLE                                         VARCHAR2(14)
 DEFERRED                                           VARCHAR2(9)
 VALIDATED                                          VARCHAR2(13)
 GENERATED                                          VARCHAR2(14)
 BAD                                                VARCHAR2(3)
 RELY                                               VARCHAR2(4)
 LAST_CHANGE                                        DATE
 INDEX_OWNER                                        VARCHAR2(30)
 INDEX_NAME                                         VARCHAR2(30)
 INVALID                                            VARCHAR2(7)
 VIEW_RELATED                                       VARCHAR2(14)

SQL>
```

Now I would like to see what's inside the CONSTRAINT_NAME column,
DESC CONSTRAINT_NAME does not work, SELECT * FROM CONSTRAINT_NAME does not work.
What's the most **simple** command to view the data from the column CONSTRAINT_NAME?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select constraint_name
  from user_constraints
```

is what you're after.  You select the column from the table.  Now, presumably, you want more information than just the name of the constraint.  You probably want to add additional columns to your `SELECT` list to get all the attributes you're interested in.